# Slow MySQL IN query -- how to convert to JOINs?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I currently have the current MySQL query taking up to 10 seconds to run in my application:

```
SELECT tagid, tag FROM tags WHERE tagid IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT tagid FROM news_tags WHERE newsid IN 
(SELECT newsid FROM news_tags WHERE tagid IN (16,32)
GROUP BY newsid HAVING COUNT(newsid)>=2)) 
AND tagid NOT IN (16,32) ORDER BY level, tagid
```

The tables used are:

- table `news_tags`, with columns `newsid`, `tagid`
- table `tags`, with columns `tagid`, `tag`, `level`

The purpose of the query is to find "news" items which have been tagged with tags with `tagid` 16 **and** 32, then find other tags these news items have also been tagged with, for the purposes of allowing a user to further narrow down the "news" items with more specific tag combinations. The ultimate goal is to grab the remaining relevant `tag` and `tagid` columns from the `tags` table.

I have tried different attempts at an equivalent `JOIN` but have failed to select all remaining `tagid`s on the news items which have the provided tags attached to them.

Here is my `EXPLAIN` SQL results, in case they point to another cause of slowness which I'm missing:

```
id|select_type       |table    |type          |possible_keys|key    |key_len|ref |rows|Extra
 1|PRIMARY           |tags     |range         |PRIMARY      |PRIMARY|      4|NULL|  55|Using where; Using filesort
 2|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|news_tags|index_subquery|tagid        |tagid  |      4|func|  26|Using index; Using where
 3|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|news_tags|index         |tagid        |PRIMARY|      8|NULL|  11|Using where; Using index
```

Just to clarify the problem: I wanted remaining tags for news items tagged with BOTH tags 16 and 32, not either 16 or 32. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags.tagid, tags.tag
FROM
       tags                             -- tags from the ...
  JOIN news_tags AS n0 USING (tagid)    -- ... news items tagged with ...
  JOIN news_tags AS n1 USING (newsid)   -- ... tagid = 16 and ...
  JOIN news_tags AS n2 USING (newsid)   -- ... tagid = 32
WHERE
  n1.tagid = 16 AND n2.tagid = 32
  AND tags.tagid NOT IN (16,32)         -- not the tags we already know about
ORDER BY tags.level, tags.tagid
```

Comment: The extraordinary thing is that this is almost identical to [an answer I gave a few days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10298855/623041) to an almost identical question.  Is this coursework?

Comment: The extraordinary thing is that your query won't do the job. See below Nawfal's answer.

Comment: @OctavianVladu: The OP asked for the tags of news items that are tagged with BOTH tags 16 **and** 32, not either-or (which is what nawfal's answer does).  Rudeness much?

Comment: I think you are over doing it by assuming `AND`. I felt `IN` stands for `OR`. I could be wrong in my understanding of OP's requirement

Comment: @nawfal: *The purpose of the query is to find "news" items which have been tagged with tags with tagid 16 **and** 32*.  Perhaps we should await the OP's clarification on what he intended?

Comment: @eggyal I do not think the purpose of the query is what you suggest. From OP's original code: `SELECT newsid FROM news_tags WHERE tagid IN (16,32)
GROUP BY newsid HAVING COUNT(newsid)>=2)`. This means he needs news_ids across tagids 16 or 32 in groups of news_id whose count >=2. This doesn't mean its an `AND` since tagid can be just 16 with many equal newsids without even having 32 anywhere. Heck, we dont even know if newsid is unique in news_tags. Yours is a bit over assumption I feel.

Comment: @nawfal: That quote was from the OP's question.  As I said, if you have any doubt, we should probably await the OP for clarification.  My reasoning was that that textual description (OP's emphasis on "**and**" btw), together with `HAVING COUNT(newsid)>=2`, suggested to me that the OP is after articles with more than just those two tags - i.e. with **both** of them.  IMHO the OP's use of `IN (16,32)` is symptomatic of the problem faced (one that is often seen here), not of desired outcome.  I have not assumed that `newsid` is unique in `news_tags`.

Comment: @eggyal peace, I get it :) But I feel the "textual" `and` here is not equivalent to SQL `AND`. He would want newsids where tagid is 16 `and` 32 which is different from `AND` in an sql. At least thats not in compliance with the query he provided. I do not think OP would mess with `AND` and `IN` as those are very trivial. I would say you should read the textual description in accordance with the query he posted, after all the title itself is to speed up query than provide him a working SQL.

Comment: Moreover (I can be terribly wrong here) there is never a way record where tagid is both 16 and 32. Your inner query `news_tags AS n1 USING (newsid) JOIN news_tags AS n2 USING (newsid)` is always going to result in empty set for `n1.tagid = 16 AND n2.tagid = 32`. Anyway peace, our own lil' misunderstanding of questions. No big deal :)

Comment: @nawfal: I disagree that my JOIN results in an empty set.  Why would it?  Suppose in `news_tags` there are `(newsid, tagid) VALUES ((1,16),(1,32))`; then n1 `(1,16)` joins n2 `(1,16)` and `(1,32)` and the filter reduces to `(1,16)` with `(1,32)`...

Comment: @eggyal Yes I get that, thanks for clarifying my misconception. But the other part holds :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, in this case I do need remaining tags from news items with BOTH tagid 16 and 32, not either.

@eggyal, your solution works beautifully -- I've already implemented it and it's very fast. I don't completely understand it's logic though, could you briefly explain it for learning's sake?

Also, I did eventually get this problem solved using JOINS instead of INs, which I posted in a solution below, I'd love to get input on  how eggyval's solution might be more optimal in cases I'm not foreseeing (other than pure cleanliness and elegance, my query is pretty damn ugly).

Comment: @SJPour: In the first comment below my answer, I posted a link to a very similar question I answered a few days ago.  in that answer, I give a very detailed explanation of how the query is built up and how performance concerns are addressed.  Perhaps you could take a read of that and come back with any questions?

Comment: Thanks eggyval, I spent a good amount of time reading your other answer and this query and I definitely understand the logic behind the statement -- really simple, elegant solution to the problem.

Even after reading your post, I'm not as sure about why exactly there's such a performance difference. Disabling my query cache and retiming all the queries, the original query runs at an average of around 7.5 seconds, my later solution below runs at an average of around 0.002 seconds and your solution runs at an average of around 0.0015 seconds. What do you think causes such a huge difference?

Comment: @SJPour: I can't say without seeing more detail - perhaps post it as a new question showing the three versions of the query, together with each query's [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) output and both tables' [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-create-table.html) statements?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: My query is strictly based on the sql OP provided, was just trying to speed up the query as was asked in question title.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.tagid, t.tag FROM tags AS t
JOIN            news_tags AS nt1 USING (tagid) 
JOIN            news_tags AS nt2 USING (newsid)
WHERE           nt2.tagid IN (16, 32) AND t.tagid NOT IN (16, 32) 
GROUP BY        nt2.newsid HAVING COUNT(nt2.newsid)>=2
ORDER BY        t.level, t.tagid
```

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually come up with a fast query that solved this problem using JOINS instead of IN statements:

```
SELECT tags.tagid,tags.tag FROM tags 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT news_tags.tagid FROM news_tags
INNER JOIN (SELECT newsid FROM news_tags WHERE tagid IN (16,32) 
GROUP BY newsid HAVING count(newsid) >= 2) tagged_news 
ON news_tags.newsid = tagged_news.newsid 
WHERE news_tags.tagid NOT IN (16,32)) rem_tags
ON tags.tagid = rem_tags.tagid
ORDER BY level, tagid
```

This is obviously no where near as clean or as elegant as eggyal's solution, so I adopted his solution in the end in my application.

I'd love to hear more objective reasons (other than elegance) for why eggyval's solution would be preferred to the above SQL statement, both to find the optimal SQL statement for the problem and also to learn for future. Appreciate all the help so far guys.

Comment: I think your solution will match articles that contain either of tags 16 *or* 32, provided that they also contain at least one other tag.

Comment: eggyval, I checked to see if that was the case, and I don't believe so. The subquery "SELECT newsid FROM news_tags WHERE tagid IN (16,32) GROUP BY newsid HAVING count(newsid) >= 2" only grabs newsid's with both tags 16 and 32, since only newsid's with two rows outputted against the where condition 'tagid IN (16,32)' (and not other tags) are kept.

Please let me know if I'm missing something, but I eye-balled the results and that's what I saw.

Comment: Test it with a news article that's tagged with `(1,2,3,16)`.

Comment: In one of your comments under @eggyal's answer you say `BOTH tagid 16 and 32, not either` and still in your query you have used an `IN`. If certainly it is an `AND` you want, just go for it by avoiding and `IN` and `GROUP BY` which is not only slower, but also has a different meaning.

Comment: In your case your query might work, but thats 'cos there are atleast two newsids with tagid either 16 or 32, or [there is atleast one newsid for both tagids 16 and 32 - which is what you want]. Think of a scenario where you have no tagid 16 in newstags and there are 2 or more records where tagid is 32 in newstags. Your query would still return records for that inner query which is not what you want as far as your textual description goes.

Comment: All I want to say is if you have clearly explained your intent in your texts rather than SQL, then pls go for @eggyal's answer. Your above query is terribly wrong in that aspect. Moreover you haven't wisely used the JOINs here which makes your query less efficient.